# How to apply distance metrics to compare bar plot (nominal histogram) data

Tags: chi-squared-test, distance, histogram, kullback-leibler, barplot

I have a data set for libraries, I would like to find the (Similarity / dissimilarity) among it based on book category, so for each category there is single value represent the number of books that belong to that category, total frequency refer to total books found in that library.

I have normalized data due to each library containing different numbers of books, as attached. My question: in order to apply these metrics for my data, how to calculate each of them to find distance (similarity) between `lib1` and `lib2` as an example. Some of these used metrics used for image retrieval and it is not suitable for nominal data.

```
•kullback-leibler-divergence
•histogram intersection distance
•Jensen-Shannon divergence
•chi-squared distance


library-name      Total-no(books)    Art    business    medicine    music 
lib1                   66             6         6          31         11
lib2                   86             9         0          12         11
lib3                   120            14        0           0         12
...
lib1000                133            15        33          2          5
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, a simple [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) might fit you well.

$cosine = \frac{\sum{A_i * B_i}}{\sqrt{\sum{A_i^2}} * \sqrt{\sum{B_i^2}}}$

Comment: Is can use for all 1000 libs , And do u mean A is lib1 and B is lib2 , I have normalized it because both of lib1 and lib2 has different frequency can you give me small notes about cosine , thanks

Comment: A is lib1, B is lib2. Use relative freqs to compare libs. Sum of rel freqs in each lib should sum up to 1.
Each lib vector should contain all categories, so if a lib does not have sports books, it should contain 0 in a corresponding component.

Comment: thanks , I did some mistakes when calculating the sum of rel.  frequency , and very thanks for explanation ,
in case need to use my submitted  metrics are it suitable for my cases or not , and if it yes what are the formula of each one for discrete data ( nominal data histogram ) thanks